# Prove that the derivative changes sign infinitely many times on either side of 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^4 \sin(1/x), &\text{when $x \ne 0$} \\
0,&\text{when $x = 0$}
\end{cases}$$

Derivative:

$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
4x^3 \sin(1/x) - x^2  \cos(1/x), &\text{when $x\ne 0$} \\
0, &\text{when $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$

I can prove that both negative and positive values exist (on either side of $0$), but how would I show that they occur infinitely often? Is induction appropriate?

Comment: Can you formulate the question using only logic symbols and stuff like $<,+, \ldots$?

Comment: You need to fix your derivative too.

Comment: @GitGud, I think I did.

Comment: @dfeuer He should do it, though. You never know, maybe he differentiated wrongly.See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10053/is-it-incorrect-to-make-edits-to-math-mistakes), by the way. Good job, though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to get across. Thank you. So would induction work?

Comment: @GitGud, under the circumstances, it seems almost certain to have been a typo. Bob, the key is to think about comparing $4x^3$ to $x^2$, and think about what the sine and cosine of $1/x$ do.

Comment: Well I understand that it would make the evaluation of the derivative vary, but how do I prove it for all x (or certain intervals)?

Comment: Induction is unnecessary. Consider $x=\pm \frac{1}{n\pi}$, also $x=\pm \frac{1}{(n+1/2)\pi}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can arrive at the conclusion without looking at the formula for $f'$. Indeed, the function $f$ is differentiable for $x\ne 0$, and $f(x)=0$ (for $x\ne 0$) precisely when   $x=1/(\pi n)$ for some nonzero integer $n$. Apply  the following lemma on each interval between consecutive zeros of $f$.

**Lemma.** Suppose  $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and satisfies $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Then either $f$  vanishes identically on $[a,b]$, or    $f'$ attains both positive and negative values on $(a,b)$.

*Proof*. If $f$ does not vanish identically, pick $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)\ne 0$. By the Mean Value theorem, $f'$ somewhere has the same sign as $f(c)-f(a) = f(c)$, and somewhere it has the same sign  as $f(b)-f(c)=-f(c)$. Thus, $f'$ attains values of opposite signs.